# Create table creates two tables with the same name in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, create-table

As I'm running the query:

```
CREATE TABLE ordered_service_history
(
  id BIGINT,
  state_shifted DATETIME,
  state VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I get two tables in the database with the name ordered_service_history.

If I drop ordered_service_history both tables will be dropped.
What could be a common reason for this type of behavior?
I only want one table with that name.

Comment: Are you certain that you software client isn't just being flaky and showing two tables? You can't have two tables with the same name in the same database. In other words.. how do you KNOW that there are two tables with the same name?

Comment: When you say you get two tables, where do you see the two tables?  This seems remarkable given the query shown and the fact that duplicates names are not permitted in SQL Server...

Comment: Actually yes, it was a problem in SQL Squirrel... I should remove the question.